# Can't cast to NSMutableString in Swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablestring

I have Swift struct like this:

```
if(isSearching == true){
    let contactDict :NSDictionary = self.filteredArray?.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary;
    let strArray :NSArray = contactDict.object(forKey: kName) as! NSArray
    nameString = strArray.componentsJoined(by: "") as! NSMutableString

    //nameString = (contactDict.object(forKey: kName) as? String as! NSMutableString)
    companyNameString = (contactDict.object(forKey: kCompanyName) as AnyObject).object(at: 0) as? NSString;
    designationString = (contactDict.object(forKey: kDesignation) as AnyObject).object(at: 0) as? NSString;
    profileImage = contactDict.object(forKey: kProfilePic) as? UIImage;
    connectStatus = contactDict.value(forKey: kLinkStatus) as? NSString;

    if(profileImage?.accessibilityIdentifier == "Img_placeholder"){
        profileImage = nil;
    }
```

The error showing like this :

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1b5b89900) to 'NSMutableString' (0x1b5b959c0)

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: It's a pain to use Objective-C types in Swift. Use Swift dictionaries, Swift arrays and Swift strings instead.

Comment: Agree with sweeper, Dont know why ppl use obj types in swift.

Comment: Someone written the code Sweeper ., I'm fixing the bugs and modifies the code..Can u explain briefly? How can i do this? In which line can i changed to NSTaggedPointerString?

Comment: @PrathapReddyJakkireddy: Have you seen my post below?

Comment: Actually, This code written by someone., and I'm converting to swift 4 in Xcode 9.2. these types of bugs were coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `nameString` to be a `NSMutableString`, then try this:

`nameString: NSMutableString = strArray.componentsJoined(by:"").mutableCopy()`

Comment: Glad I could help you. If this solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: It's working fine @user2782993., but , it doesn't filter the records.

Comment: You need to provide the filter code, this part of the code is not visible in the one you provided. You should also post a new question for this and explain what you tried so far etc.

Comment: Thank u @user2782993.,                  let strArray :NSArray = self.filteredArray?.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSArray;
The Error showing like this    Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1b5b8a800) to 'NSArray' (0x1b5b89950)

Comment: You should really post a new question! The problem is that your strArray contains NSDictionary objects. You would need to change the line back to: `let strArray: NSDictionary = self.filteredArray?.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary` or  simply `let strArray = self.filteredArray?.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary`. I don't know why you are posting the line with NSArray in your comment. Please ask a new question. Learn about casting objects. You will make a lot of people angry if you continue here and  I also shouldn't continue helping you here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from

```
nameString = strArray.componentsJoined(by: "") as! NSMutableString
```

because you can't downcast here. `NSTaggedPointerString` is a (private) subclass of `NSString` but not of `NSMutableString`. You should create a new mutable string instead:

```
nameString = NSMutableString(string: strArray.componentsJoined(by: ""))
```

But as @Sweeper said in the comments it should be better to use Swift strings.

Comment: Yes @clemens., Now., It is showing error like this Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads. – Prathap Reddy Jakkireddy

Comment: Not exactly. NSMutableString may have better performance in concatenating strings.